# Save pretty JSON file using Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

Jackson version 2.15.2

To save a json file I use the following code:

```
mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValue(file, object);
```

that I use quite often and it was working as expected, until now when I try for the first time to save a List of objects.

Expected result:

```
[
   {
      "firstName":"a",
      "lastName":"a"
   },
   {
      "firstName":"b",
      "lastName":"b"
   },
   {
      "firstName":"c",
      "lastName":"c"
   }
]
```

but the written file looks like that:

```
[ {
  "firstName" : "a",
  "lastName" : "a"
}, {
  "firstName" : "b",
  "lastName" : "b"
}, {
  "firstName" : "c",
  "lastName" : "c"
} ]
```

Is there any other configuration that I can use to obtain the expected result?

Comment: Sounds like Jackson changed the implementation to be a bit more information-dense. A welcome change, if you ask me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by setting the padding of the arrays as follows:

```java
try (OutputStream ous = Files.newOutputStream(file)) {
    DefaultPrettyPrinter prettyPrinter = new DefaultPrettyPrinter();        
    prettyPrinter.indentArraysWith(DefaultIndenter.SYSTEM_LINEFEED_INSTANCE);

    mapper.writer()
          .with(prettyPrinter)
          .writeValue(ous, list);
}
```